# How to dislay mismatch lines when comparing two text files?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.Net. I've implemented scripting to compare two text files that checks if the value or data is different from each other. The only problem is it shows only one line instead of two

Below is the data that is in text A and C:

**Text A:** `Orange,Apple,Mango,Strawberry,Banana`

**Text B:** `Orange, Apple, Mango, Blueberry, Grapes`

Here is my script

```
Sub Main()
    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim objFile1, objFile2, objFile3
    Dim objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\A.txt", ForReading) 'Current.txt represents Text from AWS network
    Dim strAddresses, strCurrent, strNoAddress
    strAddresses = objFile1.ReadAll
    objFile1.Close()

    objFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\C.txt", ForReading) 'Current.txt represents Text from Shell network

    Do Until objFile2.AtEndOfStream
        strCurrent = objFile2.ReadLine
        If InStr(strAddresses, strCurrent) = 0 Then
            strNoAddress = strCurrent & vbCrLf

        End If
    Loop

    objFile2.Close()

    objFile3 = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Scripts\Differences.txt")

    objFile3.WriteLine(strNoAddress)
    objFile3.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this vb.net or perhaps vbscript?

Comment: This is vbnet. Sorry but I'm new to programming.

Comment: Methods like "CreateObject()" are from the old days of VB6 and VBScript.  Techniques like these are not typically used in modern VB.net.  What version of Visual Studio / VB.Net are you programming with?

Comment: I see. Thank you for the advice. Currently I'm using VB.net 2013

Comment: In .NET, we typically use the .NET framework to do operations.  In this case, such as opening and reading a file, we would use the System.IO namespace of the .NET framework.  Specifically, we'd use a StreamReader.  A relatively good tutorial on VB.Net text file operations can be found here:  http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets8p2.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because you overwrite `strNoAddress` everytime the `if` conditions is `true`:

```
strNoAddress = strCurrent & vbCrLf
```

So when you hit `Blueberry`, `strNoAddress` becomes `Blueberry\n`.
When you hit `Grapes`,  `strNoAddress` becomes `Grapes\n` instead of `Blueberry\nGrapes\n`.

You want to concatenate the strings instead:

```
strNoAddress &= strCurrent & vbCrLf
```

---

A more "up-to-date" version of your code without the legacy/leftover functions of VB6 could look like:

```
Dim addresses = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Scripts\A.txt")

Dim noAdress = String.Empty
Using reader = new StreamReader("C:\Scripts\B.txt")
    Do Until reader.EndOfStream
        Dim current = reader.ReadLine
        If Not addresses.Contains(current) Then
            noAdress &= current & Environment.NewLine
        End If
    Loop
End Using
...
```

Or, to make it even more simple (good enough for small files, and without a trainling newline):

```
Dim fileA = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Scripts\A.txt")
Dim fileB = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Scripts\B.txt")
Dim noAdress = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, fileB.Where(Function(b) Not fileA.Contains(b)))
```

Comment: Thank you this work as intended. Thank you very much!